# Formatting Properties using hashtables in powershell

Tags: function, date, powershell, formatting, format

Very new to powershell  and  stack overflow (first post in fact).

Basically I have a script that queries WMI and returns certain properties then creates a html report.

i Have a function

```
function Get-InstalledSoftware {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][string]$ComputerName
    )
    $pkgs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $ComputerName

    foreach ($pkg in $pkgs) {
        $props = @{'Name'=$pkg.name;
                   'Version'=$pkg.version;
                   'Vendor'=$pkg.vendor;
                   'Installed'=$pkg.installdate}
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props}
    }
```

the function works fine except for the fact that the install date format is 
presented  as YYYYMMDD  for example 20150619.

I would like the format to be DDMMYYYY 
the -format command does not work and due to my lack of experience i'm yet to try and find a better way to do this.

thank you in Advanced!  Let me    know if there is anything i can help you with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
'Installed'=[datetime]::parseexact($pkg.installdate, "yyyymmdd", $null).tostring("ddmmyyyy")
```

Comment: thank you so much man, It works a charm ! but before i put it in my script i'll do a little research to see what that actually does and how to use  .NET never the less my question has been answered so thank you !

Comment: @Lucas Glad to help, and sorry for missing some explication but msdn do it better ;)

Comment: just in case anyone stumbles on the post check this out [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w2sa9yss(v=vs.100).aspx)